# signature hdr data: BAD, no. of bytes(9168) out of range

Tags: centos, rpm

Run command "yum update rpm",get the error:"signature hdr data: BAD, no. of bytes(9168) out of range".

My system is CentOS 8. When I tried to download software using the command

```
 yum install git
```

I encountered the error. I referred to a solution online at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cento-os-8-not-updating. However, when I used the command

```
yum update rpm
```

I encountered the same error. To execute this command, I need to install "tpm2-tss," but installing this package also results in the same error:

```
"error: /var/cache/dnf/BaseOS-ee7d6bcc3944df92/packages/tpm2-tss-2.3.2-5.el8.x86_64.rpm: signature hdr data: BAD, no. of bytes(9168) out of range."
```

How to solve this problem, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome this same issue by executing:

```
curl https://vault.centos.org/8.5.2111/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-gpg-keys-8-3.el8.noarch.rpm -o centos-gpg-keys-8-3.el8.noarch.rpm
rpm -i centos-gpg-keys-8-3.el8.noarch.rpm
```